# Getting current page in CakePHP pagination

Tags: cakephp

On one of my webpage, I show a list of customer details with default pagination [Paginator helper]. Each customer row has a corresponding 'edit' button which when clicked shows a DIV populated with that customer information. [This DIV has textboxes etc. where I can change customer info] After re-entering/modifying customer details, when I click on "Save" button, 2 ajax calls are made..

1. First one to save the edited record
2. The second one Updates the customer Listing on the same page with modified information

My problem : If I am on page 3 and edit one customer record, the 2nd ajax call refreshes the list but does not go to the page 3. It starts from page 1.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current page here:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => ('{:page}')
      )); ?>
```

This is part of the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current page here:

```
$this->request->params['named']['page']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the link from Paginator? It maintains the page # to the controller.

Something like

```
// same parameters as $this->Html->link
<?php echo $this->Paginator->link( ... ) ?>
```

Check also the [reference documentation for the Paginator Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery / javascript to store the page on a cookie and then read it from the controller.

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// on action click remember current page

```
$('td.actions').click( function( event )
{
    var page = $('li.active a').html();
    var name = window.location.href.split('-').join('_').split('/').pop();

    $.cookie.raw = true;
    $.cookie( 'CakeCookie[' + name + '_page]', page, { expires: 365, path: '/' } );

});
```